# How properly display custom widget in header with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I created and registered widget. Everything looks cool with no errors. However, if i want to display widget by name for example in header (i am using custom widget area), it does not work. It creates all divs, but with no data included. If i am using code to display all widgets in that area - it works.

**Question:**

How to display widget by name?

**Codes:**

***it displays all custom widgets in that area***

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'header-widget' ) ) : ?>
  <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'header-widget' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

***Codex says, that this should work. However, it does not.***

```
<?php the_widget( 'widget_simple' ); ?>
```

Thanks for any answers and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use the_widget, you need to supply the information that is normally supplied in the widget box on the WordPress Widget page.

So you would need:

```
<?php the_widget( 'widget_simple', $instanceData, $args ); ?>
```

$instanceData are any parameters you support in your widget, and $args are the parameters you specify when you define a sidebar, e.g. 'before_widget', 'after_widget', etc.

Both are optional, but if your widget requires some inputs (e.g. a post ID) and you don't specify $instanceData, then it's probably not going to do anything.

For example, if you wanted to display a standard WordPress text widget, the values would be:

```
<?php the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Text', array('text' => 'your text') ); ?>
```

since 'WP_Widget_Text" is the class of the standard text widget and 'text' is the parameter that specifies what test should be displayed.

Comment: Widget is simple textarea. Only simple text. Your code does not work :/

Comment: I enhanced the answer. See if that makes it clearer.

Comment: Still does not work. I am playing with default twentythirteen theme. I created widget which name is widget_simple. Also i created custom area. If you can, please check full code: http://pastebin.com/WzusH8TG

Comment: Based on you code, you should be using <?php the_widget('widget_simple', array('simple_text' => 'your text')); since 'simple_text' is your instance variable.

Comment: Nice, we are doing some progress. Now it works. But, how i can change "your text" to text that is inserted into widget? I am trying to use variable, but with no success.

Comment: You should be able to use a variable. Is it available at the point that you call the_widget?

Comment: I mean, that in backend, i inserted some text into widget. I tryed to use same $simple_text, but with no success. No error, no nothing. I need to display that inserted text at header.php. Thats why i created custom area. I dont know how to say, maybe my english is broken, but as i said before, i just need to display simple text which i inserted into widget.

Comment: If you are going to use the_widget in your header, you will probably want to create a function in your functions.php to get the text. Then you can just  say array('simple_text' => my_fn_to_get_text()).

Comment: Maybe. But why if i am using <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'header-widget' ); ?> code, it displays all widges in that area. Why cant i display only one widget by name? Codex says that i can do that, but in this situation - it just does not work....

Comment: If you use a sidebar, WordPress takes care of a lot of things for you. If you use the_widget, then you have to do all of the work yourself.